# Layered Popup not connecting to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, plugins, popup

Please I'm having issues installing "Layered Popups" on my website. It is refusing to connect to the database...

Here is the code

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //

/** The name of the database */
define('DB_NAME', '#####databasename');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', '#####username');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '#####password');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

and then I included this....

```
$connection = mysql_connect("############my sql server addreess", 
    "#####username", 
    "#####password"); 

mysql_select_db("layeredpops", $connection);
```

but it still can't connect. What do I do?

I created a new database for it. Is that why it isn't connecting?

The error is.... "Could Not Connect"

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Try this `$connection = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);` - `mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $connection);` use your constants instead.

Comment: the error it brings up is that it could not connect.

Comment: But you did replace the `#####databasename` with the actual database name and so on?

Comment: thanks for helping...found the problem. It was the hostname, I didn't specify :D